# Finding duplicates on a composite key in Excel

Tags: excel

I have a spread sheet with table data which is formatted like this:

ID 1 | ID 2 | Name | Date | Address | (etc.)

ID 1 and ID 2 is supposed to be a composite key and should not repeat. How should I go about **finding** duplicate composite keys in the **entire** sheet? Some of the answers presented here either 1) simply don't work or 2) only compares with the next row.

Note: I would prefer not to use VBA, as VBA takes a while to code (as opposed to formulas, that is)

Note 2: I am using Excel 2010

Comment: what version of Excel are you using?  Excel 2007 and later has built in conditional formatting to find duplicate values (and remove them if you're so inclined).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For Excel-2007 and later, you can use `COUNTIFS` like I mentioned my other comment:

```
=COUNTIFS(A:A, A2, B:B, B2)
```

In a helper column. Any key that appears more than once will have a count above 1, so you can easily identify them through a filter.

You can also use this in conditional formatting like @sous2817 mentioned in their comment. If you want to apply it to the whole table, then you will need to lock some references like so:

```
=COUNTIFS($A:$A, $A2, $B:$B, $B2)
```

---

For Excel-2003, you can use `SUMPRODUCT`:

```
=SUMPRODUCT((A:A=A2)*(B:B=B2))
```

And if you use it in conditional formatting, it's the same locking precaution:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(($A:$A=$A2)*($B:$B=$B2))
```

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine Well, from the looks of the two cells, they appear similar, which leads to hidden values: 1. Does the column B contain whitespaces or something that is not visible? 2. Does the date in column A contain time as well? Could it be that the time is different?

Comment: column A is of type date whereas column B is of type general. However, converting column A to number (and therefore checking timestamp vlaue) results the same: http://tinypic.com/r/2wmnwaa/8

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine Could you check out this [google-spreadsheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1imSKFZKmfAJnsWC1QwJtZCRtVvnn3PYICXwGco-70zQ/edit?usp=sharing)?

Comment: Google Drive
The app is currently unreachable

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine Okay... what do you get if you try `=AND(A4=A5,B4=B5)` to see if they are equal in excel?

Comment: I get all FALSE. But this is only comparison to the next row though

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine Okay, there's definitely something not exactly the same there. Try using the sumproduct one, with a slight variation: `=SUMPRODUCT((INT($A$2:$A$13)=INT(A2))*(TRIM($B$2:$B$13)=TRIM(B2)))` (change the range accordingly).

Comment: no luck :( http://tinypic.com/r/25z6t51/8. I am using Excel 2010 on Windows 7 Enterprise Edition. The 2 'fake' keys I just typed by hand and don't contain any hidden data. I really don't know why your formulas don't work :(

Comment: blocked by my company's firewall...I think that goes for every file upload site.

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine Could press `F9` to check whether automatic calculation is on or off? If it's off, it will take the value of the first result only.

Comment: @EvilWashingMachine Awesome! I should have thought about it way before, oh well. You're welcome!

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Remove Duplicates feature to do this easily. Just select your table and click `Remove Duplicates` on the Data ribbon.

[image]

Then check the two ID columns in the Remove Duplicates dialog. This will remove duplicate composite IDs.

[image]

Output:

[image]

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I'm very sorry, I had a misleading title. I wanted to FIND them, not REMOVE them!

Comment: Ah, thanks for editing your title. I leave my answer here just in case someone stumbles across this and actually needs to remove the duplicates, not just find them.